# Saving Django Wizard: not quite magical

Tags: django, forms

Can anyone help me figure out how to save my django `FormWizard`? I have searched and read the docs for days, but cannot figure out why my wizard will not save.

Form:

```
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class StepOneForm(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES)
    ....

class StepTwoForm(forms.Form):
    main_image = forms.ImageField()
    ....

class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        instance = MyModel()
        for form in form_list:
            for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                setattr(instance, field, value)
        instance.save()
        return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

Models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    year = models.IntegerField(('year'), max_length=4, choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/main/')
    .....

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        slug = '%s %s %s %s' % (self.user, self.year, self.model, self.series)
        unique_slugify(self, slug)
        super(MyModel, self).save()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user, self.year)
```

The traceback suggests that the error is from my models where I am over-riding the save method to create a slug. This worked fine when I was using a `ModelForm`, but seems to be causing an issue with the `FormWizard`.

```
Traceback:
File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in dispatch
  223.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in post
  286.                 return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in render_done
  328.         done_response = self.done(final_form_list, **kwargs)
File "/myproject/myproject/forms.py" in done
  55.         instance.save()
File "/myproject/myproject/models.py" in save
  95.         slug = '%s %s %s %s' % (self.user, self.year, self.model, self.series)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __get__
  343.                 raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /wizard/
Exception Value:
```

Can you help me figure out how to save the wizard, or how to remedy this error? Thanks for your ideas!

---

EDIT: after implementing @Rohan's suggestion.

```
Traceback:
File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in dispatch
  223.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in post
  286.                 return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in render_done
  328.         done_response = self.done(final_form_list, **kwargs)
File "/myproject/myproject/forms.py" in done
  56.         instance.save()
File "/myproject/myproject/models.py" in save
  97.         super(MyModel, self).save()
File "/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1593.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  910.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: InternalError at /wizard/
Exception Value: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Comment: your view combined function based and class based which is not applicable.

Comment: @cathy: There is no view for this. Instead, I followed the wizard documentation and created a generic view using a url like this: `url(r'^wizard/$', CreateWizard.as_view([StepOneForm, StepTwoForm)),`. I am following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) very closely, but am not sure why there is an error. If you have any ideas I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most likely, `self.user` in `save()` method is giving you the problem. It it not getting set when you are trying to create instance and then save it.

In your `done()` method you need to set `instance.user` to expected value before saving it.

Comment: Thanks @Rohan. I think I understand, but maybe you could help me clarify? If I try to add request to done method like this: `def done(request, self, form_list, **kwargs):` so that I can set `instance.user = request.user`, I get a TypeError: `done() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`. Is this what you mean? If so maybe I need to create my own class inheriting from `SessionWizardView` and allow request to be passed? But I'm not fully sure this is the right approach.. Any pointers in the right direction are really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `request` is attribute of `SessionWizardView` class, so you can get it  as `self.request.user` in `done()` method.

Comment: Thank you @Rohan! But another error has occurred instead, unfortunately. I posted the traceback above. If you have any ideas, I would really appreciate your input. Thanks again